Facing issue when using "subprocess.run" and "cat"
For some reasons, I need to move from os.system to subprocess.run to concatenate files (can be ASCII files but also binary ones).
While it works fine under Windows (anaconda), the following snippet seems blocked or waiting for something under Linux (Ubuntu): what am I missing?
Note a.txt and b.txt just contain a single (ascii) word.
import os, subprocess
Path = os.getcwd()
bottomFile = 'b.txt'
topFile = 'a.txt'
resultFile = 'c.txt'
    
command_line = f"cat {Path}/{topFile} {Path}/{bottomFile} > {Path}/{resultFile}"
args = command_line.split()
subprocess.run(args, shell = True)


Is it possible that Path contains a space, or some other character that requires quoting or escaping on the command line?

I reproduced the issue on Linux with space-free paths, so it's not the primary problem. But @jasonharper is right, it would be safer to put quotes in the command line, e.g., command_line = f"cat '{Path}/{topfile}' ..."

What are the some reasons to shell out to cat instead of with open("c.txt", "wb") as fo: with open("a.txt", "rb") as f: shutil.copyfileobj(f, fo); with open("b.txt", "rb") as f: shutil.copyfileobj(f, fo)?

joanis pointed on the mistake; Thanks

Note that what you're doing here has serious security problems. subprocess.run can be used in a way that's 100% safe even with malicious filenames, but you need to turn off shell=True.

@joanis, quotes don't fix the security problems because you need to worry about the malicious filename containing literal quotes that reverse the effect of the syntactic ones. Consider trying to pass cat the file created by the bash, ksh93 or zsh command touch $'/tmp/$(rm -rf ~)\'$(rm -rf ~)\'' -- that filename will cause trouble when substituted into a shell command whether or not there are quotes added surrounding the point where it's substituted in.

@CharlesDuffy Good point, thank you this this comment and your answer. I agree that is a much better solution.

When you use subprocess.run() with shell=True, the argument should be a single string with the full command line, which then gets interpreted by the shell.
Simply change your run() call to this and it all works on both Linux and Windows:
subprocess.run(command_line, shell = True)

It's when you call run() with shell=False that you need to split the command line into the program and its arguments.
Relevant Documentation
Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html
Search for shell=True on the page: under subprocess.Popen (which run() calls) there is a description of what that does, and how it differs between Windows and Linux.

A more efficient and much more secure version of your code would instead look like:
subprocess.run(
  ['cat', '--', f'{Path}/{topFile}', f'{Path}/{bottomFile}'],
  stdout=open(f'{Path}/{resultFile}', 'w')
)

Unlike the version with shell=True, this works even if your path or filenames have spaces, and a filename that contains something like $(rm -rf ~) in it won't cause your home directory to be deleted.
